# SilverStripe LookupField always displays "(none)"

Tags: php, silverstripe

Using SilverStripe 3.1 I am trying to just have a form display a specific, pre-selected, value instead of having a dropdown. Since the docs indicate LookupField being for this situation I attempted to use it, however no matter what I do it always displays (none) instead of the value I pass. It doesn't appear anyone ever had this kind of problems because Google doesn't bring up anything useful. Either that or I fail at using Google.

```
$fields = new FieldList(...);
// $user is Contact (a DataObject) or null
if ($user == null) {
    $raw = DataObject::get('Contact', 'mayContact = 1', 'sortOrder ASC');
    $list = array();
    foreach ($raw as $item) {
        $list[$item->ID] = $item->name . (empty($item->rank) ? '' : ' (' . $item->rank . ')');
    }
    $sel = new DropdownField('contact', 'Contact', $list);
} else {
    $list = array();
    $list[$user->ID] = $user->name . (empty($user->rank) ? '' : ' (' . $user->rank . ')');
    $sel = new LookupField('contact', 'Contact', $list);
}
$fields->insertBefore($sel, 'Name');
return new Form($this, 'contactForm', $fields, new FieldList(FormAction::create('send')));
```

The way I see it, it should be displaying a specific Contact Name (and possibly Rank) and the Array I pass is the same as the array that gets created, only difference being it just has a single entry as opposed to multiple when `$user` is empty.

I should probably mention that I obviously still need the value passed when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a value for the field, not just a source. The value is the fourth argument to the constructor, so you want something like:

```php
$sel = new LookupField('contact', 'Contact', $list, $user->ID);
```